# Return not working, getItemViewType behaviour is extremely weird - I cannot explain it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` Adapter and the following code inside the 'getItemViewType' method:

```
 if (position == 0) {
        return Post.PostTypeHeader;
 }
 return Container.postList.get(position).type;
```

The "position" value is 0 and when the code enters the if, it returns `Post.PostTypeHeader`. But then, immediately, it goes to the next line. HOW is that possible? I also tried with 'if' and 'else' and the code is executed in BOTH 'if' and 'else'.

[Here](http://tinypic.com/r/mj0nd0/9) is a video debugging in Android

Comment: it is not possible . just print log,v for both if and else and check what it is printing for position zero . even if in debugger it goes to next line return is Post.PostTypeHeader only.

Comment: Can you post your entire adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already answered look at
[[Simple function going past return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936479/simple-function-going-past-return-statement/38936697#38936697]) and [Android Studio debugger highlights the wrong lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805868/android-studio-debugger-highlights-the-wrong-lines).

In short try to rebuild your project, if that doesn't help you restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

It might be confusing from user's point of view while debugging is on. However, both return statements can NEVER be executed on a single flow and those are not getting executed at once indeed.

You can verify the scenario by adding two log statements like this,

```
if (position == 0) {
    Log.d("Inside if statement");
    return Post.PostTypeHeader;
 }
 Log.d("Outside if statement")'
 return Container.postList.get(position).type;
```

Only one log statment will be executed based on the value of `position`.